# Mapping a String to XWPFDocument same as console

Tags: java, xwpf

### I am using XWPFDocument for generating .docx for invoice. I have designed string look like below on console

```
    XXXX Restaurant & Cafe
      Phone No# 12131546

Invoice No. 120
Type: C-6
Customer Name:         29 05 2015
---------------------------------------
Product    Qty   Price   Total
---------------------------------------
fr. egg+toast but. jam
           1  110.0  110.0
---------------------------------------
Discount: 0%
Sub total: 110.0
Cash: 200
```

---

My code for generating .docx is:

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(FILE);                   
                    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
                     XWPFParagraph para = doc.createParagraph();
                    para.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
                     XWPFRun run  = para.createRun();
                     run.setBold(true);
                     run.setFontSize(11);
                      doc.write(output); 
                    output.close();
```

but generated .docx having text looks like:

"XXXXXX Restaurant & Cafe       Phone No# 12313531         Invoice No. 120 Type: C-6 Customer Name:         29 05 2015 --------------------------------------- Product    Qty   Price   Total --------------------------------------- fr. egg+toast but. jam            1  110.0  110.0 --------------------------------------- Discount: 0% Sub total: 110.0 Cash: 200 Balance: 90.0"

i want to get above stuff same it looks on console.Please try to help as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong with this. But as far as i remember XWPFRun ignores all \n in your string. Therefore trying to use run.setText(text) with a styled text will get you the unstyled text unfortunitly. You have to style the text creating runs.
Something like this might acctually work but i haven´t tested it right now:

```
XWPFParagraph p = doc.createParagraph();
for(Sting s:text.split("\n")){
    XWPFRun = p.createRun();
    run.setText(s);
}
```

This won´t preserve all style informations from your String. You will just have to generate the styled output by using XWPFRuns.